# Formatting hierarchical matches - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, format, hierarchy

(Note, I have not set the requirements for this)

I have two dataframes, here is a sample of `dataframe1`:

```
| Key  | Description | Type                        |
|------|-------------|-----------------------------|
| 0    | No Dept     | No Dept                     |
| 1110 | RSF         | Real Scripting Fairness     |
| 1160 | JSA         | Job Security Administration |
```

Here is a sample of `dataframe2`:

```
| Level 5 | Level 4 | Level 3 | Level 2 | Level 1 | Description2 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|-------------|
|         |         |         |         |         | All Dept    |
|         | 0000    |         |         |         | No Dept     |
|         | 1000    |         |         |         | P AND P     |
|         |         | 1100    |         |         | rsf         |
|         |         |         | 1110    |         | RSF         |
|         |         | 1150    |         |         | JSA         |
|         |         |         | 1160    |         | JSA         |
|         |         | 1200    |         |         | MLF         |
```

The idea is as follows:

1. For each key in `dataframe1`, search for it in Levels 1-4 of `dataframe2`
2. If there is a match, copy over the corresponding `Description2`, **as well as the other levels in the hierarchy**

So for example, using the entirety of the first dataframe:

```
|   | Key    | Desc   | Type                        | Description2   | Level 1   | Level 2   | Level 3   | Level 4    |   |
|---|--------|--------|-----------------------------|----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|------------|---|
|   | ------ | ------ | -------------------------   | -------------- | --------- | --------- | --------- | ---------- |   |
|   | 1110   | RSF    | Real Scripting Fairness     | RSF            |           | 1110      |           |            |   |
|   |        |        |                             | rsf            |           |           | 1100      |            |   |
|   |        |        |                             | P AND P        |           |           |           | 1000       |   |
|   | 1160   | JSA    | Job Security Administration | JSA            |           | 1160      | 1150      |            |   |
```

Then, repeat this logic for each key in `dataframe1`.

How can I accomplish this?

For testing:

```
dataframe1 = [
    {"Key": 0, "Description": "No Dept", "Type": "No Dept"},
    {"Key": 1110, "Description": "RSF", "Type": "Real Scripting Fairness"},
    {"Key": 1160, "Description": "JSA", "Type": "Job Security Administration"}
]

dataframe2 = [
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": None, "Level 3": None, "Level 2": None, "Level 1": None, "Description2": "All Dept"},
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": "0000", "Level 3": None, "Level 2": None, "Level 1": None, "Description2": "No Dept"},
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": "1000", "Level 3": None, "Level 2": None, "Level 1": None, "Description2": "P AND P"},
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": None, "Level 3": "1100", "Level 2": None, "Level 1": None, "Description2": "rsf"},
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": None, "Level 3": None, "Level 2": "1110", "Level 1": None, "Description2": "RSF"},
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": None, "Level 3": "1150", "Level 2": None, "Level 1": None, "Description2": "JSA"},
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": None, "Level 3": None, "Level 2": "1160", "Level 1": None, "Description2": "JSA"},
    {"Level 5": None, "Level 4": None, "Level 3": "1200", "Level 2": None, "Level 1": None, "Description2": "MLF"}
]

resulting_df = [
{'Key': '1110', 'Desc': 'RSF', 'Type': 'Real Scripting Fairness', 'Description2': 'RSF', 'Level 1': nan, 'Level 2': '1110', 'Level 3': nan, 'Level 4': nan},
{'Key': nan, 'Desc': nan, 'Type': nan, 'Description2': 'rsf', 'Level 1': nan, 'Level 2': nan, 'Level 3': '1100', 'Level 4': nan},
{'Key': nan, 'Desc': nan, 'Type': nan, 'Description2': 'P AND P', 'Level 1': nan, 'Level 2': nan, 'Level 3': nan, 'Level 4': '1000'},
{'Key': '1160', 'Desc': 'JSA', 'Type': 'Job Security Administration', 'Description2': 'JSA', 'Level 1': nan, 'Level 2': '1160', 'Level 3': '1150', 'Level 4': nan}
 ]
```

Comment: post `dataframe1.to_dict('list')` and `dataframe2.to_dict('list')` for testing

Comment: Ah, sorry. You are correct. Edited @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: Why `"Level 1": "1000"` should fall into result? There's no such `Key`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Because it is the top-level parent key of the match. The match is on level 2, at 1110. The level 3 hierarchy for that match is 1100, and then the level 4 hierarchy is 1000, thus, it needs to be in the result. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: by that logic `1150` is the top-level parent key for `1160`

Comment: That is correct @RomanPerekhrest -- I'm sorry I did not include that in my output; I was simply doing the first example. Let me re-edit. I apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255106/discussion-between-artemis-and-romanperekhrest).